# Hibernate SaveOrUpdate on composite key

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I have a table `(USERS)` with columns:

1. TABLE_ID - Integer
2. USER_ID - Integer
3. DATE - DateTime
4. VALUE - Double

This is mapped to a `User` class:

```
@Table(name = "USERS")
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6894800373034942671L;

@Transient
private String userName;

@Id
@Column(name = "TABLE_ID")
private Integer tableId;    

@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private Integer userId;

@Column(name = "VALUE")
private Double value;

@Column(name = "DATE")
private Date date;

public User() {

}
// Getters and setters here
```

}

Table Constraints are in place using indexes:

1. TABLE_ID - unique and clustered
2. USER_ID, DATE - unique and non clustered

I will create list of `User` objects each having a different `userId`. If for a particular `date`, there exists a User record with `userId` in the table, I want to update its `value` else insert the new `User` object.

Do I need to select using `HQL`, create new `User` objects for the ones that are missing and then run `saveOrUpdate` ? Or is there any better way ?

How can I achieve the above using hibernate ?

Answer (score -1):

SaveOrUpdate Method will be doing fine.. but dont forget if you want to update a record, you will have to fetch it from data base first for Ex:

```
//in your Dao Class 
...
public void save(User user){

     Transaction tx = null;
     Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
     try {
      tx = session.beginTransaction();
      session.saveOrUpdate(user);
      tx.commit;
     }catch(Exception e){
      tx.rollBack();
     }
}

public User getUserById(int user_id){
    User user=(User) session.get(User.class, user_id);
    return user;
}

//creating new User 
User user1=new User();
user1.setName("Mohamed");
yourDao.save(user1);


//updating an existing User
User user2=yourDao.getUserById(19);
user2.setCountry("Morocco");
yourDao.save(user2);
```